# Get cell value from Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, database, dataset

I have Table in Data Set  and when i try get cell value if value is null i get exception.  Strong Typing Exception
"The value for column Surname in table AI_PARTNERS is Db Null."
Ever time when i try turn

> partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME

if is null i get exception and can't do compare with null.

```
_partnerInfo.Surname = partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME
```

how get the value or empty string if value null?

Comment: This is typed dataset, right? And you have xsd file in the project?

Comment: Yes, this is typed dataset, and i have xsd file in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use one of the [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method overloads. Also, since you are using typed data set, there must be a generated method called `IsSURNAMENull()`.

But you can get that automatically. Open the typed dataset `xsd` file in the designer, select the `SURNAME` property, go to Properties window and change the `NullValue` property from `(Throw exception)` (the default) to either `(Null)` or `(Empty)`.

**Reference:** [Annotating Typed DataSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it's work, еhank you very much! honestly, you help me when you write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

try like this
Check your properties with `DBNull.Value` value

```
 if(partnersDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)   
 {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME))
    {
    if (partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME != System.DBNull.Value))
     {
    _partnerInfo.Surname =partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME;
     }
    }       
 }
```

Comment: i can't compare, when i call "partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME" i get exception if value null, that mean  if condition is never work if value null...